# How to get story point estimate Jira plugin development

Tags: java, jira, jira-plugin, greenhopper

I am developing a Jira report plugin. I have gathered a list of Issues and I need to find somehow the initial storypoint estimate for each of them. There is a method in the Issue class named `getEstimate()` but it returns null even for estimated tasks, and I think that this method is rather related to time estimation. Does anyone know how should I do that?

Thank you very much!

PS: I am using Java API, all information that I have so far was gathered using greenhopper classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to use the [issue.getCustomFieldValue(customField)](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/8.5.4/com/atlassian/jira/issue/Issue.html#getCustomFieldValue-com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.CustomField-) function to get that information since Jira Software works on top of Jira Core by creating custom fields.

To identify the relevant customField object, you can loop through the set returned by [fieldManager.getAvailableCustomFields](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/8.5.4/com/atlassian/jira/issue/fields/FieldManager.html#getAvailableCustomFields-com.atlassian.jira.user.ApplicationUser-com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue-) and identify the field by it's name `Story point estimate` by checking the value of [customField.getFieldName](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/8.5.4/com/atlassian/jira/issue/fields/CustomField.html#getFieldName--) or maybe by checking it's type.

[Ref](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/JIRA-JAVA-API-Story-Points-information/qaq-p/499841)